# ASP.NET MVC custom helper objects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, helper

I'm going to write a ton of helpers for my app.

For many of them I'd like not to extend HtmlHelper, but to create another helper class instead, for two reasons: 1) to be able to write, say, Link.Home and Icon.Edit instead of Html.HomeLink and Html.IconEdit; 2) to be able to easily tell standard helpers from custom ones and where the latter are defined.

Is this possible? How?

Is this not recommended? why?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be possible by subclassing HtmlHelper and calling the new class Link and Icon for example.

I would not recommend it for the simple reason that Html.HomeLink and Html.IconEdit clearly states what the method does, it outputs Html in the form of a HomeLink and and an Edit Icon.

Answer (score 4):

Well, "helper methods" are just extension methods. If you want to be able to write `Link.Home` in your views, you'll have to extend `ViewPage` and add property called `Link` of type, say, `ILink`. The `ILink` interface may itself be empty. Now all your views should inherit from `MyViewPage` and writing helper methods becomes a simple task:

```
public static string Home(this ILink link, string text)
{
     // ...
}
```